# Which Goji Berry species is for food?

Tags: plant-recommendations, lycium

Which species of Goji is edible for food purposes (not just medicinal purposes), or are they both for food? I'd like to get the one wherein the berries are used for food for our garden, but there seems to be little information on the subject available.

Is it Lycium chinense or Lycium barbarum? I heard Lycium chinense was used for food and Lycium barbarum for medicine, but I'm not convinced, since Lycium barbarum is so much more common, and I didn't find other sources to verify that.

I know they're both used for tea, and I'm pretty sure you can eat the leaves of both species (but I'm looking for something I can use for things besides tea, too).

Comment: They are squashy, dryish, and taste a little like a green pepper, salad greens, and unripe seeds lol i think they're gross

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Lycium fruit is the red berry obtained from two closely related plants, Lycium chinense and Lycium barbarum, naturally occurring in Asia, primarily in northwest China (mainly in Qinghai, Gansu, Ningxia, and Inner Mongolia, but east as far as Hebei and west to Tibet and Xinjiang).  The fruits from these species are considered interchangeable, though larger fruits are preferred and are more often found on plants of L. barbarum.

http://www.itmonline.org/arts/lycium.htm

Comment: The power of the quotation...